# Recalling a variable created in an if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, if-statement

I am iterating through files in a directory. But I only need files with .csv extension. Then I need to use the path to those files to use them later in the code. Do determine if the file is .csv I use this:

```
for subdir in os.listdir(root):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root,subdir)):
        if file.endswith(ext):
           print(file)
```

This gives me all the files with .csv extension. Now I want to create a string with the path to these files so I use this:

```
for subdir in os.listdir(root):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root,subdir)):
        if file.endswith(ext):
           
            datoteka = root + '\\' + subdir + '\\' + file
```

The path to my files is now stored in string `datoteka` and I want to use this inside this for loop. The one that also contains the if statement.

But I get an error that `datoteka` is not defined. After a quick research I found out that I can not use variables that were defined inside an If statement outside of that If statement. Is there a way to pull the variable out?

I need to preform some data analysis on the files (`datoteka` contains the path.):

```
for subdir in os.listdir(root):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root,subdir)):
        if file.endswith(ext):
            datoteka = root + '\\' + subdir + '\\' + file 
    df = pd.read_csv(datoteka, encoding = 'cp1252')
```

This gives the following error:
[image]

Is there another way I could get my paths without defining `datoteka` inside that If statemnet?

Comment: Why don't you define the variable outside your loop? You probably also need a list instead of a single string?

Comment: So you want to have multiple files or one file?

Comment: I am looking for multiple files. But I just need them to use with `pd.read_csv` one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *glob* and build a list of files like this:

```
from os.path import join
from glob import glob
from pandas import read_csv

ROOT = 'root' # root directory
SUBDIR = 'sub' # sub directory

list_of_csvs = [file for file in glob(join(ROOT, SUBDIR, '*.csv'))]

# now iterate over the list

for file in list_of_csvs:
    df = read_csv(file)
```

Or, if you don't need to keep the list of files and want a recursive search then it's just:

```
from os.path import join
from glob import glob
from pandas import read_csv

ROOT = 'root' # root directory

for file in glob(join(ROOT, '**', '*.csv'), recursive=True):
    df = read_csv(file)
```

Comment: But here I also have to define the path to the subdirectory. I only want to define the root and inside the root directory there are directories with desiret files

Comment: @CH4 You can do a recursive search using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: Similar to what I did with `os.listdir()` ?

Comment: @CH4 I will edit the answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

The variable "datoteka" is defined inside the if block so this can't be accessed outside the block, so define the variable outside the for loop.

Example :

```
for subdir in os.listdir(root):
    datoteka = None
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root,subdir)):
        if file.endswith(ext):
            datoteka = root + '\\' + subdir + '\\' + file 
    if datoteka is not None:
        df = pd.read_csv(datoteka, encoding = 'cp1252')
```

Comment: That's not how scoping works in python, but the end result is the same